# MongoDB: Query documents with a field greather than another

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible in mongoDB to query documents where a field's value is greather than another one of the same document ?

I want to query each document where a > b for documents as:

```
{
 a: Number,
 b: Number,
}
```

Is it possible to reference a field's value in query to another one ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Consider that you are trying to get the documents where a is greater than b. The code below is doing that.

```
db.collectionName.find({$where: "this.a > this.b"})
```